# C# Documentation: refer to other property

Tags: c#, code-documentation

Suppose I have this class

```
public sealed class Person 
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  public string DisplayName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

And I want to document the `DisplayName` property.

```
/// <summary>
/// A space seperated string of the FirstName and LastName
/// </summary>
public string DisplayName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

But my problem now is, what if for example I rename the property `LastName` to `FamilyName`. My code would ofcourse still compile but my documentation would refer to a non existing property.

Is there somehow a way to refer in the property `DisplayName` to the actual property `LastName` like this pseudo syntax.

```
/// <summary>
/// A space seperated string of the <prop=FirstName> and <prop=LastName>
/// </summary>
```

such that refactoring my code would also refactor the documentation or that the compiler would at least give a warning or maybe an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`<see>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#see)-tag with a code-reference-attribute (`cref`):

```
/// <summary>
/// A space seperated string of the <see cref="FirstName" /> and <see cref="LastName" />
/// </summary>
```

You can also reference members of other classes by qualifying them appropriately, e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// A space seperated string of the <see cref="AnotherClass.FirstName" /> and <see cref="MyClass.LastName" />
/// </summary>
```

or also a method:

```
/// <summary>
/// A space seperated string of the <see cref="MyMethod" /> and <see cref="MethodWithOverloads(string, int, Type)" />
/// </summary>
```